# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Collapse lays over overlapping Brand Logo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have re-done my website with Bootstrap 3.3.4. I only design desktop and mobile view.

In mobile view I am using an overlapping Brand Logo and fixed-top.

As the collapsing drop-down menu was not scrolling, I defined a max-height, now it scrolls, **but** the menu-items overlay the overlapping part of the brand logo.

This is how it looks:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ccevqogpwdxkaz0/logo-overlap.jpg?dl=0

I tried to set the z-index of the brand logo to 10000, but this did not work either.

I suspect it is the Bootstrap javascript that's putting the drop-down menu on top of the logo. (but it is still under the navbar)

A test page can be accessed here:
http://www.shaolin-wahnam-wien.at/mobiletest/TEST.html.php

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
 color: #000000!important;
 background-image: url(../bilder/pergament-pattern.jpg)!important;
 padding-top: 55px;
}
a:link {
 color: #BD0000!important;
 text-decoration: none!important;
 font-weight: normal!important;
}
a:visited {
 color: #BD0000!important;
 text-decoration: none!important;
 font-weight: normal!important;
}
a:hover {
 color:#562601!important;
 text-decoration: none!important;
 font-weight: normal!important;
}
a:active {
 color:#000!important;
 text-decoration: none!important;
 font-weight: normal!important;
}
h1 {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
 color: #BD0000!important;
 font-weight: bold!important;
 text-align: center!important;
 margin-top: 0px!important;
 padding-top: 20px!important;
}
h2 {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
 color: #BD0000!important;
 font-weight: bold!important;
 text-align: left!important;
}
h3 {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
 color: #BD0000!important;
 font-weight: bold!important;
}
.fett {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.unfett {
 font-weight: normal!important;
}
.textweiss {
 color: #FFF;
}
.sitemap-m {
 text-align: center!important;
 font-size: 1em!important;
}
.zentral {
 text-align: center!important;
}
.artikelneu {
 background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
.background-end {
 width: 945px;
 height: 12px;
}


.navbar-default {
 text-align: center!important;
 background-image:url(../bilder/pergament-pattern.jpg)!important;
 border-color: transparent!important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 5px -6px #3B3B3B;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 5px -6px #3B3B3B;
 box-shadow: 0 8px 5px -6px #3B3B3B;
}
/* Rahmen unter |||-Button nach Klick */
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: transparent!important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 color: #fbefcc!important;
} /* nav-element link-farbe */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
 color: #FFFFFF!important;
 background-color: #562601!important;
} /* aktives feld nach klick */
.dropdown-menu .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
 text-align: center!important;
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color:#fbefcc!important;
}


/* Rahmenfarbe für |||-Menubutton */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #BD0000;
}
/* Stricherlfarbe für |||-Menubutton */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #BD0000;
}
/* Hintergrundfarbe für |||-Menubutton */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
 background-color: #feda3b;
}

/* Menu-Logo hoch schieben */
.navbar-brand {
 margin-top: -8px!important;
}

.listyinyang {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-image: url(../bilder/yin-yang-taiji-list.png);
 list-style-position: inside;
}
.listwahnam {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-image: url(../bilder/shaolin-wahnam-logo-mini.gif);
 list-style-position: inside;
}
.imgleft {
 float:left;
}
.imgright {
 float:right;
}
.imgcenter {
 text-align: center;
}
.zitate {
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #562601;
 text-align: center;
}
.schriftrolle {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/schriftrolle-artikel-blog.gif);
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 10px;
 width: 297px;
 height: 105px;
}
.autor {
 text-align: right;
}
.fettmitte {
 text-align: center;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding-top: 15px;
}
figcaption {
 font-weight:bold!important;
}
.bildunterschrift {
 font-style:italic;
 text-align:center;
}
.disclaimer {
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #562601;
}
#kursfenster {
 padding-left: 0px!important;
 padding-right: 0px!important;
}
.outlined {
 outline: 1px solid black!important;
}
.kurstabelle {
 width:100%!important;
 text-align:center!important;
}
#qigongplan {
 border-color: #562601!important;
}
#qigongplan2 {
 border-color: #562601!important;
}
#preisliste {
 border-color: #562601!important;
 font-size:: 1.3em!important;
}
.kurskalender {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/kurs-kalender.gif);
 background-position:center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-align:center;
}
#lehrplan > tr > td {
 vertical-align: top!important;
}
.spacer {
 height:20px;
}
.rahmen {
    border-style: solid!important;
    border-width: 8px!important;
    border-image: url(../bilder/menu/blog-artikel-rahmen.png) 8 8 repeat repeat!important;
 -moz-border-image: url(../bilder/menu/blog-artikel-rahmen.png) 8 8 repeat repeat!important;
 -webkit-border-image: url(../bilder/menu/blog-artikel-rahmen.png) 8 8 repeat repeat!important; 
 -o-border-image: url(../bilder/menu/blog-artikel-rahmen.png) 8 8 repeat repeat!important; 
}
#qigonguebungen {
 margin-left:50px;
}
#qigonguebungen dt {
 width:350px;
 max-width:90%;
}
.dl-horizontal dt {
 text-align: left!important;
}
.img-responsive {
 display: inline-block!important;
}




.btn-primary {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #562601!important;
  border-color: #000000!important;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  color: #fff!important;
  background-color: #BD0000!important;
  border-color: #000000!important;
}















.navlogo {
 z-index:10000!important;
}





/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
p {
 font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
td, th {
 font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
li {
 font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
.dl-horizontal dt {
 font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
.dl-horizontal dd {
 font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/button-bg-brown.png);
 margin: 5px!important;
} /* nav-element link-farbe */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #FFFFFF!important;
  background-image: url(../bilder/menu/button-bg-brown-dark.png)!important;
} /* nav-element link-farbe hover & focus */
.navbar-nav > li > a {
 font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
.navbar-nav > li:first-child {
 margin-top: 35px!important;
} /* abstand vor erstem li-element */
.nav>li:last-child {
 margin-bottom:15px;
} /* abstand nach letztem li-element */
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
 font-size: 1.3em!important;
 color: #7a563a!important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/button-bg-brown-dark.png)!important;
 color: #fbefcc!important;
}
/* Anpassungen für mobile menü-höhen */
.nav>li {
 min-height: 35px!important;
}
.navbar-fixed-top .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .navbar-collapse {
 max-height: 300px!important;/* 600px entspricht idealer höhe, ist aber nicht scrollbar! */
}




.imgleft {
 margin-right: 10px;
}
.imgright {
 margin-left: 10px;
}
.inhaltsangabe, .inhaltsangabe a:link {
 font-size: 1em!important;
}
.schriftrolle {
 margin-top:10px;
}
.disclaimer {
 font-size: 12px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #562601;
}
#trainingszeiten {
 width: 90%!important;
 border: 1px!important;
 border-color: #562601!important;
 font-size: 1em!important;
}
.tabellenschriftklein {
 font-size: 0.5em!important
}
#qigongplan {
 font-size: 0.5em!important;
}
.videobeschriftung {
 font-size: 1em!important
}

#5elementediv {
 padding-left:0px!important;
 padding-right:0px!important;
}
#5elemente {
 border-color: transparent!important;
 max-width: 100%!important;
 overflow-x: auto!important;
 overflow-y: auto!important;
}
#4img {
 margin-left: 0px!important;
}
#4imgrechts {
 margin-left: 0px!important;
 margin-right: 3.95%!important;
}
#4imgmitte {
 margin-left: 3.95%!important;
 margin-right: 3.95%!important;
}
.kurskalender {
 font-size: 14px!important;
}
.blogbild {
 padding-top: 15px!important;
 padding-bottom: 15px!important;
 z-index: 50!important;
}
#kontaktformular {
 width:350px!important;
 padding-right:20px!important;
}
#googlemap {
 width:95%!important;
 height:300px!important;
}




.responsive-video {
 position: relative;
 padding-bottom: 56.25%;
 padding-top: 15px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.responsive-video iframe,
.responsive-video object,
.responsive-video embed {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 max-width: 560px;
}

.btn-primary {
  font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.active,
.open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
  font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
.form-control {
 font-size:1.3em!important;
}
form .form-group .control-label {
 font-size: 1.5em!important;
}
#tel-link {
  font-size: 1em!important;
}



}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
body {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif!important;
 font-size: 14px!important;
 line-height: 1.42857143!important;
 color: #000000!important;
 background-image: url(../bilder/shaolin-lion-marble-background.jpg)!important;
 background-position: 50% 0%!important;
 padding-top: 0px!important;
 text-align: justify!important;
}
.navbar {
 position: relative!important;
 margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}
.navbar-default {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/shaolin-wahnam-wien-menu3.gif)!important;
 background-color: transparent!important;
 border-color: transparent!important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0!important;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0!important;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 0!important;
}
.nav>li {
 position: relative!important;
 display: block!important;
 width: 98px!important;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
 padding-top: 5px!important;
 padding-bottom: 0px!important;
 line-height: 20px!important;
 font-weight: bold!important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color:#000000!important;
} /* nav-element link-farbe */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #BD0000!important;
  background-color:transparent!important;
} /* nav-element link-farbe hover & focus */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
   background-color: transparent!important;
} /* aktives feld nach klick */

.dropdown-menu {
 background-image:url(../bilder/pergament-pattern.jpg)!important;
}
.dropdown-menu .divider {
 height: 1px;
 margin: 5px 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #562601;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #000000!important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #BD0000!important;
}
.dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color:#BD0000!important;
}
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
} /* open dropdown on hover */




.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #555;
    background-color: transparent!important;
} /* keine auswirkung */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color:#BD0000!important;
  background-color: transparent!important;
} /* keine auswirkung */



.header1 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/shaolin-wahnam-wien-schule-header.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header2 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/shaolin-qigong-qi-gong-chi-kung-energiearbeit-energie.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header3 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/shaolin-kung-fu-shaolinquan-kampfkunst.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header4 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/tai-chi-chuan-tai-ji-taijiquan-kampfkunst.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header5 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/qigong-qi-gong-chi-kung-tai-chi-chuan-taijiquan-kungfu-kung-fu-kurse-seminare.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header6 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/qigong-qi-gong-tai-chi-chuan-taijiquan-kungfu-kung-fu-erfahrungsberichte-testimonials.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header7 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/blog-artikel-qi-gong-qigong-tai-chi-chuan-taijiquan-shaolin-kung-fu.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header8 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/qi-gong-qigong-kung-fu-kungfu-tai-chi-chuan-taijiquan-schule-kurse-wien-kontakt-formular.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.header9 {
 background-image: url(../bilder/menu/kung-fu-tai-chi-chuan-qi-gong-foto-video.gif);
 margin-top: 20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}




.background-end {
 margin-left: -80px;
 margin-right: -80px;
 height: 12px;
 margin-bottom: -10px;
}
h1 {
 font-size: 19px!important;
 padding-top: 30px!important;
 font-weight: bold!important;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 16px!important;
 font-weight: bold!important;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #BD0000;
}
.mainbg {
 background-image: url(../bilder/pergament-background.gif);
}
.main {
 padding-left: 80px;
 padding-right: 80px;
}
.nav.navbar-nav li versetzt {
 padding-top: 5px;
}
.sitemap {
 text-align: center!important;
 font-size: 10px!important;
 background-image: url(../bilder/taijiquan-tai-chi-schwert-jian.gif)!important;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 50% 0%;
}
.imgleft {
 margin-right: 25px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.imgright {
 margin-left: 25px;
 margin-top: 5px;
}
.schriftrolle {
 font-size: 14px!important;
}
.inhaltsangabe, .inhaltsangabe a:link {
 font-size: 13px;
}
#kursemitte {
 margin-left: 3.95%!important;
 margin-right: 3.95%!important;
}
#kurselinks {
 margin-left: 0px!important;
 margin-right: 3.95%!important;
}
#kurserechts {
 margin-left: 3.95%!important;
 margin-right: 0px!important;
}
.kurstabelle {
 width:240px!important;
 text-align:center!important;
}
#qigongplan {
 margin-left: 10px!important;
}
#trainingszeiten {
 width: 300px!important;
 border: 0px!important;
}
.rahmen {
 height:112px; 
 padding-top:12px;
}
#kurskalender {
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.img-responsive { /* nötig für 4img bei SKF - eventuell nur für ID anlegen, wenn wo anders problematisch! */
 max-width:none!important;
}
.testimonials {
 font-size: 12px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.testimonials > li {
 list-style-position: inside;
}
.form-control {
 font-size:14px!important;
 height: 45px;
}
form .form-group .control-label {
 font-size: 16px!important;
}



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Artikel / Blog - Qi Gong Übungen - Die 18 Lohan Hände</title>
    <meta NAME="description" content="Die 18 Lohan Hände sind das erste Set an Qi Gong-Übungen, die im Shaolin-Tempel durch Bodhidharma zur Förderung der Gesundheit der Mönche gelehrt wurden.">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/wahnam.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row hidden-xs"> <!-- / Header-Bild Desktop -->
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <header class="header7"> <a href="index.php#"><img src="bilder/menu/qi-gong-kung-fu-tai-chi-menu-logo.gif" width="231" height="250" alt="Shaolin Wahnam Wien Logo"/></a>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"><!-- / NAVIGATION START -->
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" href="#"><img src="bilder/shaolin-wahnam-institute-brandlogo.png" width="84" height="84"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                     <li><a href="index.php">Shaolin Wahnam</a></li>
                        <li><a href="energiearbeit-qi-gong.html.php" title="Shaolin Qi Gong (Qigong, Chi Kung)" target="_self">Shaolin Qi Gong</a></li>
                        <li><a href="kampfkunst-kung-fu.html.php" title="Kampfkunst Shaolin Kung Fu" target="_self">Shaolin Kung Fu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="kampfkunst-tai-chi-chuan.html.php" title="Kampfkunst Wahnam Tai Chi Chuan (Taijiquan)" target="_self">Tai Chi Chuan</a></li>
                        <li><a href="schule-kurse-seminare.html.php" title="Shaolin Qi Gong, Shaolin Kung Fu und Tai Chi Chuan Kurse" target="_self">Kurse &amp; Preise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="erfahrungsberichte-testimonials-schueler.html.php" class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" title="Erfahrungsberichte / Testimonials unserer Shaolin Qi Gong-, Shaolin Kung Fu- und Tai Chi Chuan-Schüler" target="_self">Erfahrungsberichte</a>
                        <a href="erfahrungsberichte-testimonials-schueler.html.php" class="hidden-xs" title="Erfahrungsberichte / Testimonials unserer Shaolin Qi Gong-, Shaolin Kung Fu- und Tai Chi Chuan-Schüler" target="_self">Erfahrungs-<br>berichte</a>
                        </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <!-- Video-Menü nur am Handy sichtbar -->
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Fotos &amp; Videos<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <a href="foto-video.html.php" title="Videos & Fotos von Shaolin Qi Gong, Shaolin Kung Fu, Tai Chi Chuan" target="_self" class="hidden-xs">Fotos &amp;<br>Videos<span class="caret"></span></a>                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="foto-video.html.php" title="Video-Übersicht" target="_self">Übersicht</a></li>
                        <li><a href="foto-video.html.php#qigong" title="Qi Gong Videos" target="_self">Shaolin Qi Gong</a></li>
                        <li><a href="foto-video.html.php#shaolin-kung-fu" title="Shaolin Kung Fu Videos" target="_self">Shaolin Kung Fu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="foto-video.html.php#taijiquan" title="Tai Chi Chuan Videos" target="_self">Tai Chi Chuan</a></li>
                        <li class="divider hidden-xs"></li>
                        <li><a href="foto-video.html.php#fotos" title="Fotos" target="_self">Fotos</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <!-- Wissenswertes-Menü nur am Handy sichtbar -->
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Wissenswertes<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <a href="artikel-blog-info.html.php" title="Blog-Artikel über Shaolin Qi Gong, Shaolin Kung Fu, Tai Chi Chuan und Zen" target="_self" class="hidden-xs">Wissens-<br>wertes<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm"><a href="artikel-blog-info.html.php" title="Blog-Artikel" target="_self">Übersicht</a></li>
                        <li><a href="artikel-blog-info.html.php#allgemeine-artikel" title="Blog-Artikel, Allgemeines" target="_self">Allgemeines</a></li>
                        <li><a href="artikel-blog-info.html.php#wahnam" title="Blog-Artikel, Shaolin Wahnam & Großmeister Wong Kiew Kit" target="_self">Wahnam &amp; WKK</a></li>
                        <li><a href="artikel-blog-info.html.php#qi-gong" title="Blog-Artikel, Shaolin Qi Gong" target="_self">Shaolin Qi Gong</a></li>
                        <li><a href="artikel-blog-info.html.php#kampfkunst" title="Blog-Artikel, Kampfkunst Shaolin Kung Fu &amp; Tai Chi Chuan" target="_self">Kampfkunst</a></li>
                        <li class="divider hidden-xs"></li>
                        <li><a href="artikel-blog-info.html.php#links" title="Fotos" target="_self">Links</a></li>                        
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                        <li><a href="schule-kontakt-info-anmeldung.html.php" title="Anmeldung und Kontakt zu unserer Kursen und Seminaren" target="_self">Kontakt</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
              </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- / NAVIGATION ENDE-->
    <div class="row"> <!-- / Inhalt START -->
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="mainbg">
              <div class="main">
                    <h1><br>
                    Test</h1>
                    <p class="fett zentral"><br>
                </div><!-- / Ende main -->
              </div><!-- mainbg ENDE-->    
              </div>
    </div><!-- / .row ENDE-->
</div><!-- / .container ENDE-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to replace img tag with this one
<img src="bilder/menu/qi-gong-kung-fu-t
ai-chi-menu-logo.gif" class="img-responsive" alt="Shaolin Wahnam Wien Logo"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You element must be absolutely or relatively positionned when you use z-index.

Comment: No, the problem was not solved yet.

I added position:relative to the brand logo. now it works perfectly!

Thank you very much for the hint! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a height for the menu in mobile view and remove the margin set for the first child element of the list.

Remove:

```
.navbar-nav > li:first-child {
  margin-top: 35px !important;
}
```

and Add:

```
@media (max-width: 468px) {
  .navbar-header {
    min-height: 95px;
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Navbar Fix]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.

This method works, but I'm losing the overlapping which I like very much. 

Bbemol solved the problem. I added position:relative to the logo, then z-index worked!

Comment: Oh I see. No problem, Yes! Bbemol's solution works in that case.